# How to implement dynamic BigQueryIO inputs

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam on Google Data Flow.

My pipeline reads from BigQuery, but it depends on execution parameters.
I should be able to run the pipeline with one point(lontitude, latitude) and several points as well.

For only one point the solution is straight forward: I can put the query as ValueProvider.

```
select * 
from UserProfile 
where id_ in ( select distinct userid 
               from   locations 
               where  ST_DWITHIN(ST_GeogPoint(longitude, latitude),
                                 ST_GeogPoint(10.9765,50.4322),
                                 300)
             )
```

The problem is when I have more than 1 points to run the query for them.
I tried to apply BigQuery read on each point and union the results in one PCollection, but I don't have any idea how to pass the points to the pipeline and build it dynamical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of points is not too huge (I would say less than a thousand), one simple way to run this query is to provide a single string with WKT description of the point collection:

```
select * 
from UserProfile 
where id_ in ( 
    select distinct userid 
    from   locations 
    where ST_DWITHIN(ST_GeogPoint(longitude, latitude),
                     ST_GeogFromText("MULTIPOINT((10.9765 50.4322), (10 50))"),
                     300)
    )
```

The WKT string should be simple to build in your code.

If the number of interesting point is larger, I would go with a table of points, and do a JOIN between locations tables and interesting points table:

```
select * 
from UserProfile 
where id_ in ( 
    select distinct userid 
    from   locations as l, interesting_points as p
    where ST_DWITHIN(ST_GeogPoint(l.longitude, l.latitude),
                     p.point,
                     300)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put those geo points first into a table (lets say `my_points_table`) and then fetch them in a subquery:

```
select * from UserProfile where id_ in 
   (
     select distinct userid from locations l 
     left outer join my_points_table t on 1=1
     where 
      ST_DWITHIN(
        ST_GeogPoint(l.longitude, l.latitude),
        ST_GeogPoint(t.longitude, t.latitude),
      300)
   )
```

Comment: why LEFT join? left join keeps all userid values, probably opposite of what's needed

Comment: It should allow to compare every `l` with every `t`. I think this is what is asked.

Comment: LEFT OUTER makes JOIN keep all left rows, even if no match is found - so it will keep all userid, regardless of match.

Comment: ..which can be filtered, yes. Its a rough idea to demonstrate how all `l` can be compared with all `t`. Of course, there are better ways,